# Unable to set value to DatePicker-Selenium WebDriver Python

Tags: selenium, search, datepicker

I'm trying to parse the HISTORICAL DATA that exists in the URL attached at the end of this question. The initial page view lists only around 45 rows of data, and I'm trying to get all of the data by changing the date range and then iterating over each page.

First, I change the date to start from 2000/01/01 and then click "Apply", then "Search". But I'm facing an issue that is redirecting me to the "OVERVIEW" page.

```
driver.get(url)

#entering the start date 'From'
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="themeBody"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[1]/input'))).send_keys('2000/01/01')

#clicking the 'Apply' button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="themeBody"]/div[4]/div[3]/div/button[1]'))).click()

#clicking the 'Search' button

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="reloadHistoricalData"]'))).click()
```

Also I get this error:

```
  Message: 
  Stacktrace:
  #0 0x55d611b76553 <unknown>
  #1 0x55d611861183 <unknown>
  #2 0x55d611897619 <unknown>
```

The URL:

```
https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/tadawul/market-participants/issuers/issuers-directory/company-details/!ut/p/z1/pZLLToNAFEC_pQvW93Z41h0OCAglmVJqmY2ZVvpIeKVSDf16p2hi2ihqnN0k58zknlzgsAReiZf9VrT7uhKFvGfceIz9iPpokdBz5yrahjOlszggiAgPPUAItcYTDSOMzLEEPAzYVFORqcD_5HtBbKLNbH9xt5CoRf7no_Y7H785Nv7kZ9I3PwFM04kEVMqYoxP0dEiAA3_OxWG9Y8f80EFGVOv8L798Gn3iSNMNQ4dK81b_AIbSXgJftBsEznF6YGD6e-Dbol69b8KubZsbBRVsxZN4PRaKrLOuy0ZUXdKVq1pC_WxJXl13uQpnGdCUaZouT_NN4878U7Sh9mj0BqnL79k!/p0/IZ7_NHLCH082KGET30A6DMCRNI2086=CZ6_NHLCH082KGET30A6DMCRNI2000=LA0=/#chart_tab2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply prepare result date string and then clean input and paste it there.
[image: details]

as i see, the format is "Year/month/day - Year/month/day" So you can get current date using datetime( or any other date) to get your "start" date then add or subtract delta and get your "second" date.
in code it will looks like:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

first_date = datetime.datetime.now()
second_date = first_date + timedelta(days=5)
#in fact both can be any datetime objects
```

and you need to format it to result string using **strftime** function:
about: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime

```
#strftime convert datetime object to string using format
result_date = f"{first_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')} - {second_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')}"
```

in result you will get sth like this
[image: details]

and then you can clear your input
using .clear() or "Ctrl + A -> delete" method

```
input_date_element = driver.find_element_by() #here your selector

#by .clear() //not works for everytime :(
input_date_element.clear()

#by Ctrl + A -> delete // I prefer that because it is more "realistic"
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

input_date_element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
input_date_element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
```

In the end send you result date string:

```
input_date_element.send_keys(result_date)
```

remember to click on Search button :)

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan for your answer, I've applied your steps but still, it redirects me to the OVERVIEW page instead of reloading the same page with the corresponding data!